# Which camera i can use in my laptop to have more better quality then Iphone tiny camera?

Tags: linux, camera, iphone, windows, high-definition

I was looking to iphone and i was surprised the quality of such tiny camera.

Is there any alternative camera for my laptop to have similar or much better then the one in iphone? So that i can use it from my laptop, but have very sharp HD quality with maximum megapixel + highest frame per second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Note: This is a shopping question BUT this is NOT a shopping answer per se. It is a "do your homework as well as you can before asking and you will get better results, and here is how to do it and why you want to" type answer :-). As such it is applicable to both shopping and technical questions and may (or may not) have a place here.

The technically competent may enjoy the last two references.

---

This is very very much a shopping type question. It doesn't need to be. This is probably not the right place for the question regardless, but you would help yourself by learning how to ask it better. (Questions that relate to "shopping" re electronic design decisions have their place here, I think (fwiw)).

In this case (and in most cases) if you do your homework BEFORE asking questions like this you will be better able to judge if the answers are good ones.

Note that high megapixels and high photo quality are not identical - BUT you asked in terms of megapixels. If you are not 100% sure that a feature such as megapixels is directly related to another attribute such as quality then you should be exceptionally careful about talking about one when you mean the other. eg the Sony A850 & A950 DSLR cameras have 24+ MP sensors and produce the most detailed studio shots available from  a 35mm DSLR camera. But if you take photos on low light or focus on (pun almost intended) sports photography then a 12 MP Nikon D700 or the even better D800s will produce vastly superior "quality". So, here, 12 MP >> 24 MP for "quality".

The "clear" answer to your question is:

- "The camera that you can find advertised that you consider is much better then the one on an iphone because you understand the differences - and which has 1080p video, and AVCHD and/or 50p or 60p rating, and which has the highest possible megapixel rating for still shots (probably in the 12-20 MP range, but maybe higher)."  Whew!

While this answer has replaced your general terms with "buzz words" / jargon they are the sort of terms that you are going to underatnd at least a little in order to make a good choice. If you ask general questions, as you have done, without doing any homework re the terminology used and the facilities available, you run the severe risk of accepting a recommendation that is uninformed and that does not meet your needs as well as they could have been met.

- eg "What is the difference between (720i), 720p, 1080i, 1080p,  what do these terms mean, and why should you care?. And do you care?"

A little searching will produce comments like:

- The AVCHD video format specification has been updated to include 1080 60p and 50p video. The AVCHD 2.0 standard has been approved by Sony and Panasonic - the co-promoters of the format. The move also includes additional support for high definition 3D movies in the format. Up until now, both companies have made high-end camcorders that incorporated out-of-specification 60p video in what was otherwise an AVCHD arrangement.

Which will help guide further searching as you begin to better understand the subject.

Research 1080p (and the others mentioned above - you want 1080p)
Research 50p, 60p, AVCHD - what you want is less certain. But when you have finished you will know what you want and why.

- Google (www.google.com)  is your great friend.
- www.altavista.com is a pretty good friend as well - sometimes better than Google.

So, all that said, the following may give you a good start on your quest:

- 720p - 720 lines of video - better quality than "TV"
- 1080i / 1080p - 1080 lines of video - better quality than 720. You want 1080p - see below.
- xxxi = interlaced - picture is delivered in two consecutive "frames" each having half the information. Standard TV does this. Lower cost to implement and to transmit. Has "issues" Avoid.
- xxxp = non interlaced. All picture information in one "frame". Better quality. Buy it
- 50p / 60p = 50 or 60 frames per second. Faster than TV (50i or 60i) or "standard " video 30x (or film at 24fps but a whole new (vast) subject). 50p for 50 Hz mains areas (eg UK). 60p for 60 Hz mains areas (eg USA). Much better potenr=tial motion handling and slo-mo and ... than 30p etc.
- AVCHD Wikipedia - AVCHD. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVCHD

---

Also:

Steven says this looks better - [Search the web for 1080p 50p 60p:](http://us.yhs4.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=A0oGdOT_8SJOXmoAzB.l87UF;_ylc=X1MDMjE0MjQ3ODk0OARfcgMyBGZyA2FsdGF2aXN0YQRuX2dwcwMwBG9yaWdpbgNzeWMEcXVlcnkDNTBwIDYwcCAxMDgwcARzYW8DMQ--?p=50p+60p+1080p&fr=altavista&fr2=sfp&iscqry=)

[24p](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24p)

[1080p 50p samples](http://vimeo.com/groups/native1920x108060pclips/videos/10737780). Wow.
Note that the 1080 affects the resolution and the xxxxp and 50p affect the motion handling.

[50p and slow motion playing](http://philipbloom.net/2009/11/27/7d-t2i-50p60p-into-slow-motion-with-premiere-pro/)

[Brain hurting time](http://www.avchduser.com/articles/canon_progressive_modes.jsp#DVX100) :-)
24PA, 24F, 24P, 25F, 25P, 30F, 30P explained

[Deep magic](http://www.poynton.com/PDFs/Magic_Numbers.pdf). Only for techo-freaks

Comment: Gee Russell, I still always find your answers so difficult to read! Have you ever tried to create real hyperlinks? It's as simple as link text between square brackets, followed by link in parentheses. Readability will be much better.

Comment: About quality and resolution: quality is mostly dependent on the lens quality. I learned this when I was used to working with good quality lenses on a 35mm camera, and switched to Hasselblad. Wow! The kind of detail that gives you! And no, that's not just because it has a higher resolution. It's the lens. Never used my 3K worth of 35mm gear anymore.

Comment: thanks for giving it a go! Mind if I spruce it up a little more?

Comment: @Russell McMahon, @Stevenvh: And also what it has to do with AVCHD? When it will be used for A to B call? (not for recording)

Comment: In general AVCHD, is used for traveling or going to moon and keep a records, to see in in earth when we are back. I do not see AVCHD tail or head related to this.